# Do we have to compile after web.config change?

Tags: web, config

I am making the following entry to appSettings in web.config file:

```
<add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="2001" />
```

Do I have to re-compile the whole application to make it work??

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is watched. You could just try it.

AppDomain it's running on ceases to take new work, and a new one is started.